# VBA Excel get value from Double Letter columns

Tags: vba, excel

Hey all I am wondering how to go about getting a value from a double letter column.

As an example:

[image]

I'm trying to get the value **2015** from the above and I am currently using this VBA code:

```
Dim theyear As String
                    
theyear = Range("AE5:AI5")
```

But that gets me an error of **Type Mismatch**.

How does one get values from double letter columns?

Comment: Which cell is the 2015 in?  If it is just in AE5 (and AE5:AI5 are just a merged format) then you should say `theyear = Range("AE5")`.

Comment: Ah dangit. I knew it was going to be something simple. Please write that as the official answer so that I can give you credit YowE3K.

Comment: unmerge the AE5:AI5 and you will see which cell actually holds the "2015"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 2015 is just in cell AE5 (and the cells AE5:AI5 are "merged") then you should say

```
theyear = Range("AE5")
```

(Or, better still, `theyear = Range("AE5").Value` - it's always a good idea to be explicit re the property being used.)